# What's the difference between lapply and do.call?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'm learning R recently and confused by two function: `lapply`and `do.call`. It seems that they're just similar to `map` function in Lisp. But why are there two functions with such a different name? Why doesn't R just use a function called `map`?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

There is a function called `Map` that may be similar to map in other languages:

- `lapply` returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.
- `do.call` constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.
- `Map` applies a function to the corresponding elements of given vectors... `Map` is a simple wrapper to `mapply` which does not attempt to simplify the result, similar to Common Lisp's mapcar (with arguments being recycled, however). Future versions may allow some control of the result type.

---

1. `Map` is a wrapper around `mapply`
2. `lapply` is a special case of `mapply`
3. Therefore `Map` and `lapply` will be similar in many cases.

For example, here is `lapply`:

```
lapply(iris, class)
$Sepal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Sepal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Species
[1] "factor"
```

And the same using `Map`:

```
Map(class, iris)
$Sepal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Sepal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Species
[1] "factor"
```

---

`do.call` takes a function as input and splatters its other arguments to the function. It is widely used, for example, to assemble lists into simpler structures (often with `rbind` or `cbind`).

For example:

```
x <- lapply(iris, class)
do.call(c, x)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

Comment: actually I found ``do.call`` is almost the same as ``apply`` in Lisp

Comment: isn't that last example supposed to be `do.call(cbind, x)` the current version gives me `Error in do.call(c, x) : 'what' must be a function or character string`...

Comment: @snoram That example still works. The function `cbind()` is different from the function `c()`, and although this also works, it gives different results.

Answer (score 70):

`lapply` applies a function over a list, `do.call` calls a function with a list of arguments. That looks like quite a difference to me...

To give an example with a list :

```
X <- list(1:3,4:6,7:9)
```

With lapply you get the mean of every element in the list like this :

```
> lapply(X,mean)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 8
```

`do.call` gives an error, as mean expects the argument "trim" to be 1.

On the other hand, `rbind` binds all arguments rowwise. So to bind X rowwise, you do :

```
> do.call(rbind,X)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

If you would use `lapply`, R would apply `rbind` to every element of the list, giving you this nonsense :

```
> lapply(X,rbind)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    8    9
```

To have something like Map, you need `?mapply`, which is something different alltogether. TO get eg the mean of every element in X, but with a different trimming, you could use :

```
> mapply(mean,X,trim=c(0,0.5,0.1))
[1] 2 5 8
```

Answer (score 49):

`lapply` is similar to `map`, `do.call` is not. `lapply` applies a function to all elements of a list, `do.call` calls a function where all the function arguments are in a list. So for a `n` element list, `lapply` has `n` function calls, and `do.call` has just one function call. So `do.call` is quite different from `lapply`. Hope this clarifies your issue.

A code example:

```
do.call(sum, list(c(1, 2, 4, 1, 2), na.rm = TRUE))
```

and:

```
lapply(c(1, 2, 4, 1, 2), function(x) x + 1)
```

Answer (score 38):

In most simple words:

1. `lapply()` applies a given function for each element in a list, so there will be several function calls.
2. `do.call()` applies a given function to the list as a whole, so there is only one function call.

The best way to learn is to play around with the function examples in the R documentation.

Answer (score 23):

Although there have been many answers, here is my example for reference.
Suppose we have a list of data as :

```
L=list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
```

The function lapply returns a list.

```
lapply(L, sum)
```

The above means something like below.

```
list( sum( L[[1]]) , sum( L[[2]]))
```

Now let us do the same thing for do.call

```
do.call(sum, L)
```

It means

```
sum( L[[1]], L[[2]])
```

In our example, it returns 21. In short, lapply always returns a list while the return type of do.call really depends on the function executed.

Answer (score 15):

`lapply()` is a map-like function. `do.call()` is different.  It is used for passing the arguments to a function in list form instead of having them enumerated.  For instance,

```
> do.call("+",list(4,5))
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 7):

The difference between both are :

```
lapply(1:n,function,parameters)
```

=> This send 1,parameters to function
=> this sends 2,parameters to function
and so on

```
do.call
```

Just sends 1…n as a vector and parameters to function

So in apply you have n function calls,in do.call you have just one