# Applying the same function for multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I am a new R user and I meet problems with my code. I have 16 different dataframes and I would like to apply the same function for each dataframe. Then, I want to put all the result in the new dataframe.
I wrote this code and it works well :

```
    df2012<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2012$year,database2012$nivvie_dec,weights=database2012$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2012$annee<-"2012"
    df2011<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2011$year,database2011$nivvie_dec,weights=database2011$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2011$annee<-"2011"
    df2010<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2010$year,database2010$nivvie_dec,weights=database2010$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2010$annee<-"2010"
    df2009<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2009$year,database2009$nivvie_dec,weights=database2009$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2009$annee<-"2009"
    df2008<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2008$year,database2008$nivvie_dec,weights=database2008$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2008$annee<-"2008"
    df2007<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2007$year,database2007$nivvie_dec,weights=database2007$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2007$annee<-"2007"
    df2006<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2006$year,database2006$nivvie_dec,weights=database2006$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2006$annee<-"2006"
    df2005<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2005$year,database2005$nivvie_dec,weights=database2005$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2005$annee<-"2005"
    df2004<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2004$year,database2004$nivvie_dec,weights=database2004$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2004$annee<-"2004"
    df2003<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2003$year,database2003$nivvie_dec,weights=database2003$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2003$annee<-"2003"
    df2002<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2002$year,database2002$nivvie_dec,weights=database2002$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2002$annee<-"2002"
    df2001<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2001$year,database2001$nivvie_dec,weights=database2001$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2001$annee<-"2001"
    df2000<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database2000$year,database2000$nivvie_dec,weights=database2000$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df2000$annee<-"2000"
    df1999<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database1999$year,database1999$nivvie_dec,weights=database1999$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df1999$annee<-"1999"
    df1998<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database1998$year,database1998$nivvie_dec,weights=database1998$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df1998$annee<-"1998"
    df1997<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database1997$year,database1997$nivvie_dec,weights=database1997$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df1997$annee<-"1997"
    df1996<-as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(database1996$year,database1996$nivvie_dec,weights=database1996$wprm),total=FALSE))
    df1996$annee<-"1997"
    df19962012<-rbind(df1996,df1997,df1998,df1999,df2000,df2001,df2002,df2003,df2004,df2005,df2006,df2007,df2008,df2009,df2010,df2011,df2012)
```

However, it is a long code and I need to replicate for others variables like sex, educational levels and family structure instead of year... I looked for a shorter code using `lapply`, but all my tentatives failed. Someone knows a way to shorten the code ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: This is not a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) so it will be difficult for others to help you. Perhaps you can create some fake data sets / data.frames? You will likely want to write a simple function.

Comment: i'm sure you want `df1996$annee<-"1996"` and not `df1996$annee<-"1997"`
Where the 17 databases are comming from? (into R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a list of Dataframes:

```
yDF <- function(y) {
  db <- get(paste0("database", y))
  df <- as.data.frame(cprop(wtd.table(db$year,db$nivvie_dec,weights=db$wprm),total=FALSE))
  df$annee <- y
  df
}
years <- 1996:2012
L <- lapply(years, yDF)
```

... normaly I am not a friend of get().
you also can do rbind() for a long dataframe:

```
DF <- yDF(1996)
for (y in 1997:2012) DF <- rbind(DF, yDF(y))
```

Answer (score 2):

Again, see my comment to generate a new example, but the following should get at the core elements of your question and is reproducible. Walk through each portion slowly to understand what's going on. In general, you should strive for [D.R.Y. code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) when possible and get in the habit of writing [small/simple functions](http://sam-koblenski.blogspot.com/2014/01/functions-should-be-short-and-sweet-but.html) anytime you find yourself repeating lines of code:

Make two "fake" data.frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 11:20)
```

A simple "dummy" function `h(x)`, rather, `h(df)`, takes a `data.frame` and creates a new column `y` by taking the dataframe's existing `x` column and adding `10`.

```
h <- function(df) {
  df$y <- df$x + 10
  df
}
```

Find all the objects of the pattern `df-any-number` and store them in `dfs`:

```
dfs <- ls(pattern = "df[0-9]")
dfs
```

Run `lapply` over `dfs` by searching by name (i.e. `mget`) and apply function `h` to each of them. Finally, `rbind` the results via `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(dfs), h))

#         x  y
# df1.1   1 11
# df1.2   2 12
# df1.3   3 13
# df1.4   4 14
# df1.5   5 15
# df1.6   6 16
# df1.7   7 17
# df1.8   8 18
# df1.9   9 19
# df1.10 10 20
# df2.1  11 21
# df2.2  12 22
# df2.3  13 23
# df2.4  14 24
# df2.5  15 25
# df2.6  16 26
# df2.7  17 27
# df2.8  18 28
# df2.9  19 29
# df2.10 20 30
```

---

Some posts that will be helpful to guide your understanding:

- [Difference between lapply and do.call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10801750/2572423)
- [How to call an object with the character variable of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9083907/2572423)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `complete_dataframe <- rbind(...)` to combine all your data frames together, especially if they have a separate column that defines each dataframe (here it will be `annee`). Then you can use either the `data.table` package or `dplyr` package to apply a function over specific groups.

In `dplyr`, the workflow would be

```
complete_dataframe %>% group_by(annee) %>% mutate(new_var = somefunction(columns_to_pass_into_function))
```

to generate new variables, or

```
complete_dataframe %>% group_by(annee) %>% summarise(new_var = somefunction(columns_to_pass_into_function))
```

to create a summary table over the groups.